# SpriteKitNode above SKView CALayer

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, calayer, shapes, skspritenode

I have a SKScene with some SKSpriteNode and I wanted to draw a shape on CALayer of the SKScene view.

It's working well but my CALayer is always above my SKSpriteNode and I don't know how to send this layer to the back (I mean under the child of my scene)

Is it possible to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's impossible. You cannot place any of your `SKNodes` above `SKView`s `layer`.

To draw a shape use `SKShapeNode`. It's buggy in iOS 7, but people says it's been improved for iOS 8